# Upgrade Windows XP 32bit to Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, upgrade

Ive got a computer with windows XP 32bit installed on it and I want to upgrade/clean install it to Windows 7 64bit.

I've tried the following:

- booting from the CD
- booting from USB

I changed the bootoorder in my BIOs to boot from CD/USB first and I tried to format the hard drive but it won't let me do that.

None of the above have worked and I'm running out of ideas, is there anything else I can try to install a fresh version of windows?

Comment: What is going wrong when you tried installing Windows with a CD or USB?

Comment: where did you get this version of windows 7 64bit?

Comment: The only upgrade option from Xp 32 to win7 64 is a clean reinstallation. That should just work (assuming you have a 64 bit capable system, which is almost any PC from the last decade).

Comment: I've run the Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor and its says that its compatible. WHen I try to boot from the CD/USB it comes up with press any key to boot from CD, I press keys and nothing, it just continues to the loading of XP. I've also selected the boot sequence to be cd-rom after pressing f12

Comment: @TomMaton - There is no upgrade path from Windows XP x86 to Windows 7 x86 the only personal files are transfered.  Going from Windows XP x86 to Windows 7 x64 does a complete instalation not even personal files are transfered.  I am not sure what the upgrade advisor says is compatible but there is no direct upgrade path from windows xp to windows 7 period.

Comment: The Upgrade Advisor may have assumed you would be running a version of Win 7 with the same "bitness" as the version of XP you current have -- at least that what it did when I ran it on my 32-bit systems.

Comment: 32 bit to 64 bit is complete backup, disk wipe and reinstall. Back your data and Docs & Settings folder up to an external hard drive and proceed from there.

Comment: @martineau - You are indeed correct.  If he downloaded the upgrade advisor it assumes your moving to Windows 7 x86 if you are running Windows XP as this is the only possible upgrade path that keeps personal files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're running in to is your keyboard, when you see that prompt in dos that there is a bootable cd/dvd "press any key to start" etc. And you press a key, nothing happens.

This is most likely due to that fact you're using a USB keyboard, and your motherboard is so old it doesn't load usb drivers off the bat like more modern motherboards do.

GET a ps2 keyboard, and you should be fine.

[image]

Comment: this is under the assumption you are using a usb keyboard which I'm almost sure of.

Comment: He could also check to see if his BIOS has an option for enabling USB keyboard on POST.

Comment: @moses i'm waiting for him to respond to see if even has a USB keyboard first, im only assuming right now, and if the computer was built like during the windows xp time, i doubt it will have such an option, but the question is very vague as it is.

Comment: @Sickest yes I do have as USB keyboard, but I've replaced the motherboard in the past year but not sure that makes any difference.

Comment: ok, after 10 years of working on computers, im 99.9% sure this is your problem, PS/2 keyboards are like 5-10$, and they are totally worth having around for this specific problem. good luck

Comment: I'll give this a go as never originally gave this idea a thought, I'll let you know the outcome ASAP

Comment: @Sickest you are spot on mate, I' owe you a beer or two as this has been driving me nuts!!!

Comment: @tommaton np :D

Comment: Seems strange you would have to press a key if the bootoorder in BIOS was changed so the CD/DVD was first. The most amazing thing to me is that you figured-out the problem from the OP's description...

Answer (score -1):

As a last resort you can try hooking up your hard drive to another computer to format it (as a bootable NTFS partition) and connect it up again. If your working on a tower, it's handy to have a box and book around to prop your HDD on as you're doing connecting and testing. Even though new SATA drives are hot-swappable if the setting is enabled in BIOS, I would not recommend unplugging connections, especialy power directly to the back of the drive while the PC is on... fried an IDE drive this way, smoking PCB board and everything.

Answer (score -1):

One thing you did not mention is if your cpu is x64 capable,if it is then another option is to remove your drive and do the whole install on a tower as windows installs generic drivers initially,stick your drive back in and install correct drivers!

Comment: the fact he wants to install a x64 operating system it's safe to assume he has the hardware besides every ( 99% at least ) of all hardware in the last 5 years supports 64-bit